# Flask and Pytest - PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pytest, temporary-files

Following the documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/), I am trying to add tests to my flask project with pytest.

**This is my code:**

```py
import os
import tempfile
import pytest
import myapp
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, flash, g, url_for, session, abort


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    db_fd, myapp.app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
    myapp.app.config['TESTING'] = True

    with myapp.app.test_client() as client:
        with myapp.app.app_context():
            myapp.init_db()
        yield client

    os.close(db_fd)
    os.unlink(myapp.app.config['DATABASE'])

def login(client, username, password, redirect_to):
    return client.post('/login', data={
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'redirect-to': redirect_to}, 
        follow_redirects=True)

def logout(client):
    return client.get('/logout', follow_redirects=True)

def test_empty_db(client):

    rv = client.get('/')
    assert b'MyApp Name' in rv.data

def test_dashboard_logged_out(client):

    rv = client.get('/dashboard')
    assert b'Login to continue' in rv.data

def test_login_logout(client):

    rv = login(client, 
        myapp.app.config['USERNAME'], 
        myapp.app.config['PASSWORD'],
        '/dashboard')
    assert rv.status_code == 200

    rv = logout(client)
    assert b'logged out' in rv.data
```

**Problem: (ERROR at teardown of test_login_logout)**

Though all the tests are executed successfully, I see an error - `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\Claudia\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpxftp9tno'` when the line `os.unlink(myapp.app.config['DATABASE'])` is executed.

I don't have any other process using the database. I have checked everything and the only python process that runs during the test is the command prompt (escalated as administrator) running `pytest`.

Comment: Does that happen for each test, or only for specific tests? Does it happen consistently? As far as I can see this should work (provided you don't have something like a virus scanner interferring), though more information may help someone to understand the problem.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, when I run `pytest -v` it shows all tests are completed. And the error happens at 100%. And I don't have any virus scanners except Windows Defender. Ran the tests after turning off defender too. Same results.

Comment: Does it happen on _each individual_ test teardown, or only once for all tests? Have you tried to run the tests separately?

Comment: Just checked each test. The first two tests work without any issues. Ran `test_login_logout` separately. It passes but teardown causes the error.

Comment: Not sure if it could be a timing problem - easy to test by adding a `sleep` call after the `logout` call. This kind of problem only happens under Windows, maybe that is the reason it has not been noticed in the example - `unlink` under UNIX just dereferences the file, and it is deleted only after the last reference is gone.

Comment: Tried adding a `sleep` for 5 seconds after the `logout` method. Still the same.

Comment: In this case I would probably run it in a debugger and check who still has a file handle before the file is deleted (using process explorer for example), if anyone. Nothing else comes to mind at the moment...